# How to generate project files for Scala IDE with sbt-eclipse for builds with ProjectRefs?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-ide, sbteclipse

I referenced to another project using the following code in `project/build.scala`:

```
object MyProjectBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project("my-project", file(".")) dependsOn(securesocial)
  lazy val securesocial = ProjectRef(file("../../../open-source/securesocial"), "core")
}
```

It compiles and runs without any problem in Play console but (after generating eclipse project), the root project doesn't have any reference to securesocial in Scala-IDE and hence eclipse complains `not found: object securesocial` everywhere I referenced to `securesocial`.

How can I generate the references to ProjectRefs for Eclipse project?

I could solve it by adding securesocial target folder as Class Folder to the root project build path. But it should be done by Play `sbt-eclipse` plugin.

Comment: This use case isn't supported right now for eclipse.